# How to match strings with "like" keyword?

Tags: string, crystal-reports

I'm prompting the user to enter a SaleLotNumber (string) and I'm having trouble with the formula. I have multiple entries with "20" in the SaleLotNumber but when I enter that in, I don't get anything on the report. When I enter the full SaleLotNumber in the parameter, I get the specific value from the database but I would like to enter only two numbers into the parameter and get all entries with those numbers in that order. Here's what I have:

```
{viewDealers_Drivetime.SaleLot} like {?SaleLotNumber}
```

What can I do do fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that {?SaleLotNumber} is a single-value parameter. To match all strings with a "20" in them, you need to use wildcards. For example, you can match a string like "012056" or "98720" by doing:

`{viewDealers_Drivetime.SaleLot} like '*' + {?SaleLotNumber} + '*'`

where '*' is Crystal's wildcard and {?SaleLotNumber}="20"